# Is it a bad idea to put anonymous functions inside a method in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-management, iterator, closures, anonymous-function

I decided to go all jQuery* on some iterators recently, e.g.:

```
// forEach being a built-in method of myList that iterates over its members.
myList.forEach(function(i:ListItem):void {
    // Do something with i.
});
```

However, as some of this code is being called every frame, I'm finding a lot of closure allocations when I profile. I'd like to minimize GC for performance reasons, but I'm assuming that the only way I could do that is to use a named function instead of an anonymous one? If I must then I must, but it just feels clunky and hard to follow, especially since some of these methods end up having nested iterators, i.e. the members of `myList` are themselves Array-like objects and I need to iterate over THEIR members too. Do I really have to do something like the below?

```
function enterFrame(e:Event):void {
    myList.forEach(iterator1);
}

function iterator1(i:ListItem):void {
    i:forEach(iterator2);
}

function iterator2(j:ListItemItem):void {
    // Do stuff with j.
}
```

*EDIT: Let me clarify. I'm working in Actionscript 3, not Javascript. I'm referring to the fact that my code structure was inspired by my experience with jQuery, which in its documentation actively encourages the use of anonymous functions as callbacks, as in the classic `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is what Adobe has to say](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f57.html) about literal/anonymous function (which they call function expressions). If you know what you are doing, regarding garbage collection and performance, there shouldn't be a problem IMO.

In your particular case consider you will be creating a new object every time you call `forEach()`, and a new function call in every element of your list/sublist (anonymous or not).

Also consider that using the dynamic properties of AS3 (eg: untyped vars, dynamic classes such as `Object`, anonymous function, etc.) will affect performance. Of course those things are not noticeable in small projects. [Haxe](http://haxe.org/), which is a strict typed AS3 like language and also compiles to SWF, performs much better because it has dropped most of those dynamic features (it not all).

Comment: I'm using the Nape physics library, and I think it creates a reusable Iterator object for its forEach() methods. Your other points are well taken, though. I may just have to see if anything creates a performance issue. I'm trying to minimize potential memory/GC slowdown issues because I'm eventually going to be deploying to mobile devices and I'm making a game with a lot of complexity, and consequent further memory allocations, left to add.